# How can I connect Jmeter with Databricks spark cluster

Tags: azure, apache-spark, jmeter, databricks

I want to connect Jmeter with Databricks (Spark Cluster) using JDBC connection associated with that spark Cluster
I need to perform a concurrency test using Jmeter's JDBC request on a apache spark cluster using spark sql queries

Need Help

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the JDBC driver for Databricks from the [downloads page](https://databricks.com/spark/jdbc-drivers-download), and put it into JMeter's classpath. After that, configure JDBC connection as described in [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/integrations/bi/jdbc-odbc-bi.html#workspace-cluster) (basically you need to copy the JDBC connection string from cluster UI, and put your personal access token).  This JDBC connection string should be set in [JMeter's JDBC connection parameters](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-db-test-plan.html#adding_requests).

Comment: Hi Alex , Thank you

But How can I run Spark Sql queries on a JDBC request and what will be the driver class I should use

Comment: Look into documentation - it has all information

Answer (score 0):

1. Get [databricks-connect](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-connect.html#step-1-install-the-client) client:

   ```
   python -m pip install -U databricks-connect==7.3.*  # or X.Y.* to match your cluster version.
   ```
2. Run the following command:

   ```
   databricks-connect get-jar-dir
   ```

   it will return the path to the databricks client libraries. Copy them to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) and restart JMeter
3. Add [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and implement your test scenario(s) in [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black). Example code snippets can be found in [SQL databases using JDBC article](https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/sql-databases.html), just make sure to use Azure SQL Database driver

Comment: are you sure about that he needs the libraries from databricks-connect?